# How to declare stimulus target in rails link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm learning stimulus with rails and try to do a countdown on a link :

Only the countdown work fine, I get the following errors in my console and link class is not updated :

1. error: Missing target element "countdown" for "countdown" controller
   identifier: 'countdown', controller: extended, element: a#link.isDisabled}
2. Uncaught Error: Missing target element "link" for "countdown" controller

**my html**

```
<span id="countdown" data-controller="countdown" data-countdown-target="countdown"></span>
    <%= link_to 'close the windows', '#', id: 'link', class: 'isDisabled', data: { controller: 'countdown' target: 'countdown.countdown, countdown.link' } %>
```

**my stimulus controller**

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["countdown", "link"];

  connect() {
    this.startCountdown();
  }

  startCountdown() {
    let remainingTime = 8;
    this.updateCountdown(remainingTime);

    const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
      remainingTime--;
      this.updateCountdown(remainingTime);

      if (remainingTime <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);
        this.hideCountdown();
        this.enableLink();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  updateCountdown(remainingTime) {
    this.countdownTarget.innerText = remainingTime;
  }

  hideCountdown() {
    this.countdownTarget.style.display = "none";
  }

  enableLink() {
    this.linkTarget.classList.remove("isDisabled");
    this.linkTarget.classList.add("link");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything with a single `data-controller` element, then declare targets for that controller:

```html
<span data-controller="countdown">
  <span data-countdown-target="countdown"></span>
  <%= link_to "close", "#", data: { countdown_target: "link" } %>
</span>
```

You can refer to `data-controller` element itself with `this.element` inside the stimulus controller if needed.

*https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets*